# Sharing data between device in same app iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, core-data, icloud

I am planning on making an app on iPhone.
Users can take a photo inApp or upload photos from their photo library(photo stream). Once this is done, anyone else with the app should be able to see these photos IN THE APP. What is the best way to approach this? Do i require a server or is there another way to save photos. Do I have to use iCloud for this? I am under the impression that iCloud is for a single user and not to share information as a server. Should I change this impression of mine?

Thanks!

Comment: store the data in a remote server.

Comment: Why you want to avoid iCloud, when Apple is providing facility whatever you need then why you do not want to use it?

Comment: iClould is the best way to do that

Comment: Doesn't the iCloud restrict the data to one particular user? I think iCloud data is private and cannot be shared. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yeah i thought iCloud was for a particular user as well. Cool will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know what Core Data has to with it, but if you are planning to do CoreData + iCloud, I strongly suggest you to avoid it, it has some major issue that will be solved in forthcoming iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to save the photos to a server somewhere. Whenever the app runs on a given device, it'll need to check with the server to see if there are new photos to display.

Your impression of iCloud is correct -- it's for syncing data between a single user's devices, not for sharing data between many users.